# way to show row count in jsf Datatable

Tags: jsf

Hello I need the way that can add row number into jsf dataTable without external library, and I think is often needs in dataTable and we have standard way.
so what can I do for add row number in jsf background process?
Like :

```
row , name , phone
1,jake,1234564
2,alex,456789
3,sara,1235488
```

I found way Looks like this :

```
<h:dataTable 
value="#{pwaService.resultInfos}" 
var="resInfo" rowIndexVar="row"
styleClass="table user-list"
headerClass="text-center">
```

And we can use like this :

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<span>RowNumber</span></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{row + 1}"/>
</h:column>
```

is that a standard way?